# How to inject some js to the webpack only if some condition matches?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm running a webpack server with `env` variable, and test environment points my build environment:

```
var environment = process.env.environment == null ? "development" : process.env.environment
```

How can I add some js into the build depending on this `environment` value? I don't want to write ugly stuff with `DefinePlugin` and then things like:

```
if (NODE_ENV="test") {
  import { "my_polyfill" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config)

1. create a `default.js` which contains your dev webpack config.
2. create a `production.js` with the additional config over the `default.js`

By default `node-config` will pick the `default.js` and supply it to webpack.

If you set `NODE_ENV=production`, it will pick `production.js` and does a `Object.assign({}, default, production)` and supply it to webpack.

By this way, you'll be able to manage n number of `env` config for webpack.

Hop it helps!

**[UPDATE]**

Adding an example to demonstrate your case...

**Create `config/default.js` in the root of your project**

```
export default {
  entry: ['./foo/bar', './foo1/bar1'],
  output: {
     path: path.resolve('./build/js'),
     filename: '[name].js',
     publicPath: '/js/'   
  },
}
```

**Create `config/production.js` in the root of your project**

```
   export default {
      entry: ['./foo/bar', './foo1/bar1', './new/entry'], //adding the new entry
      plugins: [
       new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
         warnings: false,
        },
       }),
      ],
    }
```

**Create `webpack.config.babel.js` in the root of your project**

```
import config from 'config' //I'm using ES6 style. You can use require also

export default config.default //export the config based on the NODE_ENV
```

**Show time**

```
webpack --progress --colors
default.js as the config
```

In this case node-config will return the

```
NODE_ENV=production
webpack --progress --colors
```

In this case node-config will take both `default.js` and `production.js` and does an override over `default.js`(here the entries and the plugins from the production.js will be overridden in default.js ) and it will return a object with {entries(from `production.js`), output(from `default.js`), plugins(from `production.js`)}, which is a [Object.assign()](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhyb6_oLbPAhUCpJQKHZOlBrgQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fassign&usg=AFQjCNGDyaldaef-11acOiSsXSHcx-wh_w&bvm=bv.134495766,d.dGo) operation.

To revert back to `default.js`. You need to reset the NODE_ENV

```
NODE_ENV=
```

*Yov might need to use `export` or `exports` while doing `NODE_ENV` based on your OS*
Hope it helps

Comment: Could you show me a working example please? What should I do with `Object.assign?`

Comment: @asiniy You don't need to do anything with Object.assign(). node-config will take care of that. I'll add the examples in a bit.

Comment: What do you mean by `inject`? Add additional `entries` based on the `env`?

Comment: Pranesh, yes, I want to add additional entries

Comment: @asiniy Added examples. Check!

Comment: Man, I meant adding new file to the build, not the entry to the webpack `entries` config.